# Acumatica Modern Interface, is it possible to control the number of rows when collapsed

Tags: acumatica

When using the collapsed interface on the sales order (AKA the arrow tiny button to the right) is it possible to do one of the following:

- Change the fields it displays (eg: right now I am showing some labels for the fields below in those columns). It would be truly amazing if when I click that, I could move some of the fields from the first column to the top 2 rows. Thus, I would move the most important data from the first column to the header.
- Alternately, can you make the top be 3-4 rows instead of just 2, or is that hard coded in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Form container Autosize element and MinHeight/MinHeightLimit properties does affect the behavior of the expander but I haven't found a way to achieve the desired functionality with those.

This is the code which generates the form panel Div element:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create the content division control.
/// </summary>
private WebControl CreateContentDiv()
{
    WebControl div = this.TemplateContainer;
    this.hasStaticContent = this.AutoSizeWindow;
    if (hasStaticContent) foreach (Control c in div.Controls)
    {
        IAutoSizedControl sc = c as IAutoSizedControl;
        if (sc != null && sc.AutoSize.Enabled) { hasStaticContent = false; break; }

        var wc = c as WebControl;
        var hc = c as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl;
        if (wc != null || hc != null)
        {
            string pos = (wc != null) ? wc.Style["position"] : hc.Style["position"];
            if (pos == "absolute") { hasStaticContent = false; break; }
        }
    }

    if (!hasStaticContent && (!ControlHelper.GetHeight(this).IsEmpty || this.AutoSize.Enabled)) 
        div.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);

    // mark division as editable region
    if (this.DesignMode)
        div.Attributes.Add(DesignerRegion.DesignerRegionAttributeName, "0");
    return div;
}
```

I also found elements that suggests the 2 row value is hardcoded for the purpose of showing the expander control (if content height is taller then 2 row show expander control):

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page != null && !this.Page.IsCallback)
    {
        var gen = (PXLayoutGenerator)this.TemplateContainer;
        gen.CreateStackByRules();

        if (!this.CaptionAsLink && !this.AutoSize.Enabled)
        {
            if (this.AllowCollapse == null && gen.Rows > 2) this.AllowCollapse = true;
            //if (this.AllowCollapse == true && !this.CaptionVisible) this.CreateCollapseImage();
        }
    }
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

With JavaScript it would possible to roll your own logic to control the UI layer.
Setting the TabPanel style height property will achieve the desired rendering and it should be possible to hook the expander events too:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_phF_form_t0').style.height = '117px';
```

[image]

To re-order the editor control based on the form collapsed state is a bit more difficult depending on the layout but can be achieved similarly by setting the CSS display property:

```
var isVisible = false;
document.getElementById(alse'ctl00_phF_form_t0_edCustomerID_text').parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = isVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
```